# “OEM Unlock” unlockable

Tags: bootloader-lock

I've a very dramatic problem. I don't know how it could happen but sice a week the internal storage of my Cubot X20 Pro with android 9 is in "read only" mode. That's mean that I couldn't reset (anytime I tried, after restart, I found all like a week ago) or do something else. I spending last week looking and searching on web for a solution. I tried every guide. But nothing. The problem is that I can't switch on OEM unlock.

[image]

Without this all command on fastboot or adb will fail because the system is read only. Is a snake that eat his tail. So the question: there's a saint thatknow a program or procedure that surely work toescape that enpasse? Please I'm desperade, the phone has only 2 months of life and I can't take it on a assistance cause i've bank app and all accounts visible.

Comment: Have you tried to perform a factory reset?

Comment: if factory reset not working, try to flash empty userdata partition from SP Flash Tool. If no reset is possible sounds like data partition read-only which indicates emmc wear-out (btw unlocking bootloader will trigger factory reset)

Comment: I found this problem doing  factory reset. At the end of procedure nothing happen and that alarmed me. I also tried to flash the phone with stock rom from official site but tought flash tool say that all gone well, at restart I found the same screen of one week ago. https://www.cubot.net/platform/Support/detail/id/141/cid/10.html

Comment: did you flash userdata.img?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I followed the instruction of link above. I also tried usi magisk app and flashing boot_patched.img created with it. It's like you try to modify an old cd-rom

Comment: in SP Flash Tool you have a scatter file with list of partitions to flash. one of the partitions is named userdata

Comment: some devices run in emergency mode where the whole userdata partition is mounted read-only - that mean any changes will revert on reboot (even factory reset) i first heard about such thing 4 years ago https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3472891&page=2